# Selenium: Click on element in div container doesn't work

Tags: selenium

Fyi: I'm using the selenium package for R, the selection code is equal to javascript or python so I'm asking a general selenium question.

I have a container which I have to make visible by a click, this works.

Then I try to select an element inside this container, I think I find it correctly but the click on the element only makes the popup window disappear.

Example code:

```
<div class="dateRanges" style="top: 275.313px; display: block;">
<a class="top dateOption CUSTOM" id="id32" href="javascript:;">
Benutzerdefinierter Zeitraum
</a>
<a class="dateOption TODAY" id="id33" href="javascript:;">
Heute
</a>
...
</div>
```

Element I try to find is "top dateOption CUSTOM".

My different tries which all failed:

```
remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath','//a[contains(@class,"top")]')$clickElement()

remDr$findElement(value = '//a[@class = "top dateOption CUSTOM"]')$clickElement()

remDr$findElements(using = 'css selector','a[class="top dateOption CUSTOM"]')[[1]]$clickElement()
```

I don't get any error message, the click seems to happen as the popup disappears, but the effect of the button does not.

I tried to save the object, wait a few seconds and click afterwards with no different effect.

I also tried different approaches with "idc4" with the same outcome.

Would appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: Have You tried selector that was suggested by the browser ???

Comment: i think there are 2 possibilities either xpath that u r trying is giving u more than 1 result with one of the result element being hidden and that element is receiving the click making pop-up to disappear. else click action is not done on the element properly..in case of later..you can verify this by getting elements location..moveToElement(element) and then get click and then get location..also try running ur script in IE browser with persistent hovering enabled and u should see where does ur mouse clicks

Comment: Thank you for your advices, you were right, there were different possibilities so I had to findElements() and catch the right one.